# Dynamic Variables in Admin Tool in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am building an app which stores information about a location.  A location has a description which currently is just static text stored in the database.  I want to allow the admin to add stuff like `{{location.title}} is a cool place` in the description textfield (via the admin tool).  Then on the front end the output would be something like `LocationName is a cool place`.

I dont know what this kinda thing is called, so I am unable to find any gems that deal with this.  I could just parse the description and look for text between the {{ and }} and us this the populate the view.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you looking for some MVC javascript tool like angularJS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gsub to replace your wildcard with the actual content when you pull it out from the db.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub

```
str = "{{location.title}} is a cool place"
str.gsub!('{{location.title}}', 'foo') # "foo is a cool place"
```

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes I try to over-complicate things when the solution is so simple :)